# emacs colors based on $TERM environment variable

Tags: terminal, emacs, gnu-screen, colors, tmux

I want to know if it is possible to make emacs, when running in a gnu screen or tmux session, use the same colors as when `TERM=xterm`. In a gnu screen or tmux session,  `TERM=screen` and emacs uses a different set of colors as compared to when `TERM=xterm`.

For example, when `TERM=xterm-256color`, the foreground color of `font-lock-comment-face` is 'Firebrick'. But when `TERM=screen-256color`, it is set to 'chocolate1'.

For tmux to work properly, the TERM variable **must** be set to screen or some derivative, so resetting TERM is not an option for me.

Comment: (Wish I could comment...) It is unclear to me if you have tried running emacs as: `TERM=xterm emacs` to force the `TERM` variable setting for emacs. What happens when you do that?

Comment: I'm experimenting with that at the moment. I haven't detected any bad things happening just yet. It seems tmux can be configured to emit xterm key sequences (although TERM=xterm is still unsupported). Based on the tmux FAQ, tmux might come to support xterm in the future instead of only screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition of `font-lock-comment-face`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/110908/lisp/font-lock.el#L1875) includes many variants for cases of varying color support.

- The `chocolate1` variant is used when there are at least 88 colors available and the “background” is “dark”.
- The `Firebrick` variant is used when there are at least 88 colors available and the “background” is “light”.

The difference is caused by some code that gives special meaning to TERM values that start with `xterm`, `rxvt`, `dtterm`, and `eterm`: it considers them to have a “light” background.

You should be able to customize `frame-background-mode`<sup>*</sup> to its `light` value to always use the “light” color variants.

If your Emacs is not new enough to have its own `term/screen.el`, then you will also need to adapt one for yourself that makes the appropriate color-adjusting calls. You might use the one from [Emacs trunk](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/110908/lisp/term/screen.el), or I have [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/03101250a0c5bcc05f00) that includes a `.emacs.d/lisp/term/screen.el` (with some extra bits to recognize the modifier+arrows/Home/End sequences provided by *tmux*’s `xterm-keys` option), and the `.emacs` modification needed to let it automatically load.

Of course, there could still be other bits of code that directly check the TERM value and do something different for `screen`- and `xterm`-like values…

<sup>*</sup> M-x customize-variable frame-background-mode